# Running a function until another one would be done

Tags: python, pyqt5

My goal is to make label1 (green) be visible before label2 would be created and hide it at the end of secondLabel but when i run this code it only shows me label2 (orange).
(In my actual code the second function takes long to load that is why i added singleshot)

Only green label visible -> (about two seconds) -> Only orange label visible

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

labelList = [None, None]

def empty():
    pass

def firstLabel(frame):
    label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    label1.setGeometry(240, 80, 40, 40)
    label1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 87, 30)")
    labelList[0] = label1
    secondLabel(frame)

def secondLabel(frame):
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(window)
    timer.singleShot(2000, empty)
    label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    label2.setGeometry(20, 40, 200, 120)
    label2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 75, 20);")
    label2.show()
    labelList[1] = label2
    labelList[0].hide()

def myFunc(frame):
    firstLabel(frame)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setFixedWidth(300)
window.setFixedHeight(200)
window.setWindowTitle("Window")
window.move(100, 50)

frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(window)
frame.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 200)
frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);")
myFunc(frame)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Two things: 1. Qt is not very well suited for procedural patterns, and a more OOP approach (which involves using classes) should be preferred instead; 2. if you have a function that takes a long time to be completed, you should use a QThread, which makes almost mandatory to use classes: while it *could* be achieved without that, it will only makes things unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @musicamante I used normal threads but they didn't work. The only limit in normal thread is that you can not create qt object but you can use qt methods on them. Didnt work. Is there any way i can make this question work? (using classes etc)

Comment: @GrantWard101 please provide a [mre] with *normal threads*

Comment: @GrantWard101 That's why I talked about **QThread**. Normal python threads don't allow interaction with the main UI thread, but using signals in a subclassed QThread (or QObject subclass moved to a QThread) allows that, since signal connections are thread safe. I repeat, if you want a *valid* implementation, classes are required. Don't try to find your way through using complex and convoluted system that "work", it will only make things unnecessarily difficult (and prone to bugs and unexpected behavior); learn how classes work and how to use them.

Answer (score -3):

I managed to solve this question using time module. It is not ideal but it works for this case.

```
import time
import threading
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

labelList = [None, None]

def empty():
    pass

def firstLabel(frame):
    label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    label1.setGeometry(240, 80, 40, 40)
    label1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 87, 30)")
    labelList[0] = label1
    secondLabel(frame)

def secondLabel(frame):
    time.sleep(2)
    labelList[1].show()
    labelList[0].hide()

def myFunc(frame):
    timer.singleShot(2000, empty)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setFixedWidth(300)
window.setFixedHeight(200)
window.setWindowTitle("Window")
window.move(100, 50)

frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(window)
frame.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 200)
frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);")

timer = QtCore.QTimer(window)
label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
label1.setGeometry(240, 80, 40, 40)
label1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 87, 30)")
labelList[0] = label1

label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
label2.setGeometry(20, 40, 200, 120)
label2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 75, 20);")
label2.hide()
labelList[1] = label2

threading.Thread(target = secondLabel, args = (frame,), daemon = True).start()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a valid solution. I understand that you're using `time.sleep` instead of your long process, but that's not how UI programs should behave, as functions that take a long time should be moved to a thread so that they don't completely prevent UI interaction and proper drawing.